# SCORM 1.2 package can not able to communicate with LMS

Tags: php, scorm

Currently i'm working on a LMS system which we are designing to run a SCORM 1.2 package. I've no prior experience about this LMS+SCORM stuff.

I'm following this Stack Overflow post - http://goo.gl/Iplemq to build my LMS system. One JavaScript error I'm getting in my `player.php` file. Here is the screen shot from my chrome dev console.

[image]

Files which I'm using..

- start.php             : http://pastebin.com/vhRxYAJu
- SCORM_12_APIWrapper.html  : http://pastebin.com/eCvBprwJ
- player.php            : http://pastebin.com/3MV9m7Wi
- wrap.js           : http://pastebin.com/g56qhEiG
- index.html                : http://pastebin.com/W5KZDHGB

Any thought peoples!!!

Comment: Organize your example files in http://jsfidlle.net (use static output from start.php) - maybe the load sequence are wrong

Comment: @RagenDazs Load Sequence of which files ?

Comment: From your question. Maybe something need to be loaded in some specific sequence

Comment: @RagenDazs I don't know a lot of about LMS+Scorm things. I've just read couples of user guide & trying to do this. As showing in this post - [ http://goo.gl/Iplemq ] , i followed their procedure. But, no luck..

Answer (score 1):

None of your pastebin links includes a SCORM API. Calling getAPI() is useless if the SCORM API (`window.API` for SCORM 1.2) does not exist.

If you're planning to build SCORM support for an LMS, you need to create the API and make it available to the course. The [SCORM docs](http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/SCORM-1-2-Specification?type=technical_documentation) explain all of this.

A simple example of a SCORM API is available on the late Claude Ostyn's site. You might be able to use it as a starting point. 
http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/scorm2004testwrapwrap.htm

This one might also be useful to you:
http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/singleSCOminiRTEwrap.htm

Comment: Here is link i found http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/scorm.js . May be you are talking about this api. 

If I'm right, then can you please help me to understand where actually i need use this file ? I mean, in "SCORM_12_APIWrapper.html" or "wrap.js" file i need to use it.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart What pipwerks means is that you need to program the LMS portion of the API so that the content has an API object to find. Since the API isn't there, the content is continuously searching for an API object, or window frame named API, that doesn't exist. I would suggest taking a look at: http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/singleSCOminiRTEwrap.htm. This shows an example API. You will then need to convert this code so that the SCORM Runtine methods (LMSInitialize, LMSCommit, etc.) are accessable in a HTML frame named 'API'.

Comment: @KernelPanik : After searching a bit, i got this link - http://goo.gl/GcCj1a . I feel this is the thing which you want to tell. Also, after using this piece of code in my "wrap.js" file now, that "API Object" not found error has been removed. 

But, still I've some doubt about those, functions in that API (Ex: LMSGetValue/LMSSetValue) . I think these are the functions from LMS side which i can use to interact with my DB & send data to SCORM OBJ. But, no where in that function it has making any kind of server side call & similar to that.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart no, that file is not what you need -- it's a demo/beta wrapper for CMI5 support. Don't take this the wrong way, but building true SCORM support into an LMS is extremely difficult and requires countless hours of reading the spec. You MUST understand the spec before you build anything. The API is only scratching the surface, you also have to parse the manifest. Some companies have an entire staff working on these tasks. You might be better off finding an open-source SCORM player you can modify for your project. Try looking at the SCORM support in Moodle or Ilias.